# Java Text File I/O Location

Tags: java, file, io

I have looked at other threads on where Java looks for files, but I still find myself confused.

I have a program, created in Eclipse (Juno) as a java project. I have made no modifications to anything else, and only have a main class for now.

When the program runs, it takes three inputs: a number, and two strings. The first string is the name of the file it has to read input from, the second is the file it has to put output to.

If I pass in "input.txt" for the input string, and have a file called input.txt, where should it be for Java to find it? I have tried putting it in src, bin, and in the project root. Currently, I am trying to access the file as follows:

```
File input = new File(args[1]);
```

Where args[1] is the first string passed to the program at the start. When I do this, I get an error "java.io.FileNotFoundException: input.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)"

Where should I be putting the file so that Java can find it?

Here is the relevant code:

```
public class main {

public static int runs;
public static File input;
public static File output;

public static String line1;
public static String line2;
public static String line3;
public static String reactions;

/**
 * @param args 
 */
public static void main(String[] args){

    if(args.length != 3)
        System.out.println("Please provide 3 arguments.");

    runs = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    File input = new File(args[1]);
    File output = new File(args[2]);

    System.out.println(runs);
    System.out.println(input);


    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
```

Answer (score 3):

For questions like this, try using the getAbsolutePath() method:

```
File input = new File(args[1]);
System.out.println(input.getAbsolutePath());
```

This shows you where the file object thinks the file is. That's where you should put the file... or perhaps modify the input argument accordingly so the program looks for the file in the place where you want the file to be.

Comment: After doing this, the printed directory is the same as the directory of the file. AKA the file is where the program thinks it is.

The line actually giving an error is 

`Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);`

Comment: Are you passing in a file name or directory name?  What does the println show?

Comment: Here is my relevant code:

`File input = new File(args[1]);
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);`

Comment: args[1] is the second value passed in the arguments passed into the program at runtime. So if I run it with parameters '2 input.txt output.txt' arg[0] = 2, arg[1] = input.txt, arg[2] = output.txt. I have confirmed that these values are as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to put that input file in root folder of your project.

**UPDATE :**

As you are using scanner to get user input. then hide the code which your are using for args ie command line arguments.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
runs = sc.nextInt(); // This will store your input line  
in = sc.next(); // This will store your input file name 
out = sc.next();  // This will store your output file name
```

Comment: It is currently in the root folder of the project, and it does not work.

Comment: @elykl33t Are you sure you are keeping our file in root folder? Its supposed to work. try `./` appending to your file. However it doesnt make any difference.

Comment: Yes I have double checked that it is in the correct directory. Not sure if it matters, but the actual line that is causing me an error is `Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);`

Comment: @elykl33t Please add this code and show us updated piece of code how your are accessing elements from console

Comment: @elykl33t I updates the answer. let me know if that helps you or have any questions.

Comment: I will take a look at this further once I am out of class. Thanks a bunch for the advice! I'll be sure to let you know if I do have questions.

Answer (score 0):

If file name is not absolute (does not start with `/` on *nix and `C:\` on Windows), then it is looked in current working directory.  Java program may get its current working directory using `System.getProperty ("user.dir")`.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse you should explicitly set the execution directory for a run configuration.

The directory used by *default* can depend on project configuration, packaging, output directory, etc. so it's best to either (a) use an absolute path (e.g., prefaced with a `c:\` or `/` etc.) or (b) set it in the run config.