# Kotlin reading from file exception

Tags: kotlin, file

```
private object Bot {
    val token = File("token.txt").reader().readLines()

    fun setup() {

    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    print(Bot.token)
}
```

Even though the token.txt file is in the same directory as the Bot.kt file it throws a java.io.FileNotFoundException.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Text File I/O Location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14735575/java-text-file-i-o-location)

Comment: val token = File("token.txt").absolutePath.reader().readLines() 
I tried doing it like this, but it only prints the path for some reason not the lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you only specify `"token.txt"` it will refer to the root directory of the project not to the directory of the class that is calling. [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/java-file-path-absolute-canonical) you can see
how you can specify paths (example is in java but that is the library that kotlin JVM is using)

So in your case if you want to keep file next to the class it will probably look something like

```
File("src/main/kotlin/token.txt")
```

Or whatever your file structure looks like

Edit to explain your comment `File("token.txt").absolutePath` will return the path as the string and calling `reader().readLines()` on that will just read that returned string(path) not the contents

Comment: *it will refer to the root directory of the project* - not really. It will refer to the working directory of the java application process. If you compile the app and run it somewhere from the compiled jar, the `token.txt` path will be resolved against the current directory (the place from which you run your app). It is unrelated to the project sources.

Comment: @Joffrey Good point, you can edit my post to include that and I will accept. Or I will if you don't want to bother

Comment: Or just point to [my previous answer](/a/73802855/10134209)…